# Using CSS, how do I set the formatting of just a single cell or a single column?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Using CSS, how do I set the formatting of just a single cell or a single column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the cell a class name and style the class.

```
<td class="cellClass">test</td>

.cellClass { color: #a9a9a9 }
```

Comment: The CSS standard defines a pseudo class called **first-child** that would solve thid without specifically using a custom css class, but no browsers support it...

Comment: That CSS declaration will apply to more than one element.

Comment: In the question it was mentioned 'just a single cell' and not 'the first cell'.

Comment: @awe: All modern browsers support it, even IE8.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `ID` selector to target just that one element of the page, in this case, a table cell:

```
 <tr>
  <td id="foo"></td>
 </tr>
```

Then in the CSS:

```
#foo
{
 //-- CSS styling goes here just for this element only
}
```

That hash symbol (`#`) marks that name selector as belonging to an `id`. You can further lock it down in the stylesheet to apply only to a TD cell with that ID like so:

```
td#foo
{
 //-- CSS styling goes here just for this element only
}
```

If you add in the `rowspan` attribute into the `TD`, you'll be able to turn that into a column and keep the styling you may have set out.

```
<td id="foo" rowspan="3"></td>
```

If you mark the CSS selector name with a preceding period (.), like this:

```
.foo
{
  //-- CSS styles
}
```

that will target `class` selectors in the HTML and you can style more than one matching element if you apply the CSS class attribute to the tag, like so:

```
 <tr>
  <td class="foo"></td>
  <td class="foo"></td>
  <td class="foo"></td>
 </tr>
```

Don't use `CLASS` unless it will appear more than once on the page.

Comment: Frameworks like ASP.NET alter the ids applied to elements.  I'm certain others do the same.  If you're going to recommend against ids, it would be best to note this.

Comment: Answer written based on HTML/CSS only as question doesn't seem to mention use of any other frameworks.

Comment: @krdluzni: The example specifies id for a div tag, which is a html tag. ASP.NET never alter id's of html tags, but the ID for a .NET tag (Example: **asp:Button**) can result in a different id on the generated html tag.

Comment: Corrected use of `DIV` when question explicitly asked about `TD`.

Answer (score 1):

For table cells, you'll need to give it some sort of identifier such that you can refer to it. Depending on your needs, this will be either a class or an id.

```
<td class="specialCell">...</td>
```

In your CSS you can then apply different formatting:

```
.specialCell { color: red; }
```

If you want to apply different styles to a column, there is the [`<col>`](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/tables/col.html) tag, but browser support is limited. You're probably better to apply that class to all elements manually (or by using Javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the HTML [`<col>`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_col.asp) and [`<colgroup>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_colgroup.asp) tags, which allow you to apply formatting to entire columns or adjacent groups of columns at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can style the `COLGROUP` that applies:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #special { background:yellow }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <colgroup></colgroup>
            <colgroup id="special"></colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

give the cell/column a class or id and use css to apply the formatting to that

Answer (score 0):

you can assign two names to a column. ex

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo bar"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>

div.foo { color: #fff; }
div.bar { background-color: green; }
```

perhaps that could solve your problem?